# Most efficient way to sort a circular buffer

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting

I've implemented a circular buffer using a fixed-length array. In order to point to the start of valid data, I use an index (`_startIndex`). Similarly, in order to point to the end of valid data, I use another index (`_endIndex`). Below is an example.

```
  9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0   <-- array indices
  3   2   1   0                   5   4   <-- buffer indices
-----------------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
-----------------------------------------
              ^                   ^
             _startIndex         _endIndex
```

Now I need to rearrange the elements of this buffer: the smallest element should be moved to position 0 of the buffer, while the largest element should be moved to position 5 of the buffer.

My idea is based on the following method.

```
int GetArrayIndex(int bufferIndex)
{
    return (_startIndex + bufferIndex) % LENGTH;
    // LENGTH is the length of the array
}
```

In this way, the sorting algorithm could read the buffer sequentially, using the above method, without therefore having to be aware that the buffer consists of two non-contiguous portions of the same array.
Are there better ways to sort a circular buffer?

Comment: How important is it that you do an in place sort?  Can you just generate an `IEnumerable<T>` of your data based on the buffer, call orderby on that, and then generate a new buffer based on the result?

Comment: Is this actually sorting or is the goal to rotate the buffer so that the first elements is positioned at the first element of the underlying array?

Comment: @Servy: The buffer should contain the messages to be sent to a node in the network. How could I evaluate if I need to do an in-place sort?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: this is actually sorting.

Comment: Any particular reason why can't you simply rearrange elements to be starting from position 0 in array and use normal Sort? In any case there is O(n log n) element moves to sort them, so one extra O(n) should not be a problem...

Comment: @enzom83 Well, if you *really* need an in place sort you can always do what I described above and then just copy all of the values back into the buffer, but are you *sure* you really do need an in-place sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do an in-place sort, then you should compress the buffer first. That is, make it one contiguous block from index 0 to index 5.

Then you can call the [Array.Sort(T[], index, length)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kszeddc.aspx) overload to sort that portion of the array.

You can move the items with a single operation, once you figure out what to move, and where.

There are three cases:

1. `start_index == 0`: No movement needed
2. `start_index < end_index`: Number of items to move is `(end_index - start_index + 1)`. Move items from `start_index` through `end_index` to positions '0' through 'count-1'
3. `start_index > end_index`: There is a "hole" in the array (as you've shown). You need to move items from `start_index` through the end of the array to position `array.length - start_index - count`.

Once you figure out the source and destination positions, you can call [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) to move the items.

I should note that, after the move and sort is done, you can set `start_index` to 0, and `end_index` to `count-1`. Or, if you really want the buffer to be in the same state it was in before (just with re-ordered items), you can move things back using the same kind of logic I described above. Why you'd want to do that is unclear.

Comment: +1. Clearly most efficient from coding point of view, as efficient as anything from perf point of view - (rearranging blocks + sorting ):`O(n) + O(n log n)` ) is still `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

1. Move elements so that values occupy positions 0, 1, ... , M-1, where M is number of used positions in the array.
2. Modify _startIndex = 0 and _endIndex = M-1
3. Call Array.Sort on part of the buffer between 0 and _endIndex inclusively.

This solution runs in O(M) steps to rearrange elements and O(MlogM) to sort them, which totals O(MlogM) time. In other words - time required to rearrange elements to the beginning of the buffer is negligible compared to time required to sort them.

Alternative solution is to sort first and second part of the buffer separately and then to merge sort them to the beginning of the array. Running time is equal (slightly larger, to be precise), and code is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose implementing a modified quicksort.

quicksort is a "divide and conquer" algorithm, which means dividing the set into two pieces, and then continuing.
 your buffer is already splitted into two parts, they just need to be adjusted. the the first step would be sorting the two pieces, the first piece at the beginning of your array, and the second piece at the end of your array. you would just "presort" the elements so that every element in the second part is smaller than any part in the first part. then you can apply the quicksort algorithm to every piece and you are sorted

Comment: +0: I don't see how you can "pre-sort" without actually sorting - quick sort does not guarantee position of partition element. I think one can use merge sort as post-processing step after sorting 2 separate portions individually. Would not do that unless it is an interview question.